# How does predict.lm() compute confidence interval and prediction interval?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, prediction, lm

I ran a regression:

```
CopierDataRegression <- lm(V1~V2, data=CopierData1)
```

and my task was to obtain a

- 90% **confidence interval** for the mean response given `V2=6` and
- 90% **prediction interval** when `V2=6`.

I used the following code:

```
X6 <- data.frame(V2=6)
predict(CopierDataRegression, X6, se.fit=TRUE, interval="confidence", level=0.90)
predict(CopierDataRegression, X6, se.fit=TRUE, interval="prediction", level=0.90)
```

and I got `(87.3, 91.9)` and `(74.5, 104.8)` which seems to be correct since the PI should be wider.

The output for both also included `se.fit = 1.39` which was the same. **I don't understand what this standard error is. Shouldn't the standard error be larger for the PI vs. the CI? How do I find these two different standard errors in R?**
[image]

---

Data:

```
CopierData1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(20L, 60L, 46L, 41L, 12L, 137L, 68L, 89L, 
          4L, 32L, 144L, 156L, 93L, 36L, 72L, 100L, 105L, 131L, 127L, 57L, 
          66L, 101L, 109L, 74L, 134L, 112L, 18L, 73L, 111L, 96L, 123L, 
          90L, 20L, 28L, 3L, 57L, 86L, 132L, 112L, 27L, 131L, 34L, 27L, 
          61L, 77L), V2 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 
          10L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 
          2L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 
          2L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -45L))
```

Comment: Looking at `?predict.lm`, it says: *"`se.fit`:
standard error of predicted means"*. "Predicted means" makes it sounds like it applies only to the confidence interval. If you don't want to see it, set `se.fit = FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess what I'm asking is, how can I compute the two std errors in the picture? So I can verify the computation and know how they're derived.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

When specifying `interval` and `level` argument, `predict.lm` can return confidence interval (CI) or prediction interval (PI). This answer shows how to obtain CI and PI without setting these arguments. There are two ways:

- use middle-stage result from `predict.lm`;
- do everything from scratch.

Knowing how to work with both ways give you a thorough understand of the prediction procedure.

Note that we will only cover the `type = "response"` (default) case for `predict.lm`. Discussion of `type = "terms"` is beyond the scope of this answer.

---

### Setup

I gather your code here to help other readers to copy, paste and run. I also change variable names so that they have clearer meanings. In addition, I expand the `newdat` to include more than one rows, to show that our computations are "vectorized".

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(20L, 60L, 46L, 41L, 12L, 137L, 68L, 89L, 
          4L, 32L, 144L, 156L, 93L, 36L, 72L, 100L, 105L, 131L, 127L, 57L, 
          66L, 101L, 109L, 74L, 134L, 112L, 18L, 73L, 111L, 96L, 123L, 
          90L, 20L, 28L, 3L, 57L, 86L, 132L, 112L, 27L, 131L, 34L, 27L, 
          61L, 77L), V2 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 
          10L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 
          2L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 
          2L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -45L))

lmObject <- lm(V1 ~ V2, data = dat)

newdat <- data.frame(V2 = c(6, 7))
```

The following are the output of `predict.lm`, to be compared with our manual computations later.

```
predict(lmObject, newdat, se.fit = TRUE, interval = "confidence", level = 0.90)
#$fit
#        fit       lwr      upr
#1  89.63133  87.28387  91.9788
#2 104.66658 101.95686 107.3763
#
#$se.fit
#       1        2 
#1.396411 1.611900 
#
#$df
#[1] 43
#
#$residual.scale
#[1] 8.913508

predict(lmObject, newdat, se.fit = TRUE, interval = "prediction", level = 0.90)
#$fit
#        fit      lwr      upr
#1  89.63133 74.46433 104.7983
#2 104.66658 89.43930 119.8939
#
#$se.fit
#       1        2 
#1.396411 1.611900 
#
#$df
#[1] 43
#
#$residual.scale
#[1] 8.913508
```

### Use middle-stage result from `predict.lm`

```
## use `se.fit = TRUE`
z <- predict(lmObject, newdat, se.fit = TRUE)
#$fit
#        1         2 
# 89.63133 104.66658 
#
#$se.fit
#       1        2 
#1.396411 1.611900 
#
#$df
#[1] 43
#
#$residual.scale
#[1] 8.913508
```

> What is `se.fit`?

`z$se.fit` is the standard error of the predicted mean `z$fit`, used to construct CI for `z$fit`. We also need quantiles of t-distribution with a degree of freedom `z$df`.

```
alpha <- 0.90  ## 90%
Qt <- c(-1, 1) * qt((1 - alpha) / 2, z$df, lower.tail = FALSE)
#[1] -1.681071  1.681071

## 90% confidence interval
CI <- z$fit + outer(z$se.fit, Qt)
colnames(CI) <- c("lwr", "upr")
CI
#        lwr      upr
#1  87.28387  91.9788
#2 101.95686 107.3763
```

We see that this agrees with `predict.lm(, interval = "confidence")`.

> What is the standard error for PI?

PI is wider than CI, as it accounts for residual variance:

```
variance_of_PI = variance_of_CI + variance_of_residual
```

Note that this is defined point-wise. For a non-weighted linear regression (as in your example), residual variance is equal everywhere (known as *homoscedasticity*), and it is `z$residual.scale ^ 2`. Thus the standard error for PI is

```
se.PI <- sqrt(z$se.fit ^ 2 + z$residual.scale ^ 2)
#       1        2 
#9.022228 9.058082
```

and PI is constructed as

```
PI <- z$fit + outer(se.PI, Qt)
colnames(PI) <- c("lwr", "upr")
PI
#       lwr      upr
#1 74.46433 104.7983
#2 89.43930 119.8939
```

We see that this agrees with `predict.lm(, interval = "prediction")`.

**remark**

Things are more complicated if you have a weight linear regression, where the residual variance is not equal everywhere so that `z$residual.scale ^ 2` should be weighted. It is easier to construct PI for fitted values (that is, you don't set `newdata` when using `type = "prediction"` in `predict.lm`), because the weights are known (you must have provided it via `weight` argument when using `lm`). For out-of-sample prediction (that is, you pass a `newdata` to `predict.lm`), `predict.lm` expects you to tell it how residual variance should be weighted. You need either use argument `pred.var` or `weights` in `predict.lm`, otherwise you get a warning from `predict.lm` complaining insufficient information for constructing PI. The following are quoted from `?predict.lm`:

> ```
>  The prediction intervals are for a single observation at each case
>  in ‘newdata’ (or by default, the data used for the fit) with error
>  variance(s) ‘pred.var’.  This can be a multiple of ‘res.var’, the
>  estimated value of sigma^2: the default is to assume that future
>  observations have the same error variance as those used for
>  fitting.  If ‘weights’ is supplied, the inverse of this is used as
>  a scale factor.  For a weighted fit, if the prediction is for the
>  original data frame, ‘weights’ defaults to the weights used for
>  the model fit, with a warning since it might not be the intended
>  result.  If the fit was weighted and ‘newdata’ is given, the
>  default is to assume constant prediction variance, with a warning.
> ```

Note that construction of CI is not affected by the type of regression.

---

### Do everything from scratch

Basically we want to know how to obtain `fit`, `se.fit`, `df` and `residual.scale` in `z`.

The predicted mean can be computed by a matrix-vector multiplication `Xp %*% b`, where `Xp` is the linear predictor matrix and `b` is regression coefficient vector.

```
Xp <- model.matrix(delete.response(terms(lmObject)), newdat)
b <- coef(lmObject)
yh <- c(Xp %*% b)  ## c() reshape the single-column matrix to a vector
#[1]  89.63133 104.66658
```

And we see that this agrees with `z$fit`. The variance-covariance for `yh` is `Xp %*% V %*% t(Xp)`, where `V` is the variance-covariance matrix of `b` which can be computed by

```
V <- vcov(lmObject)  ## use `vcov` function in R
#             (Intercept)         V2
# (Intercept)    7.862086 -1.1927966
# V2            -1.192797  0.2333733
```

The full variance-covariance matrix of `yh` is not needed to compute point-wise CI or PI. We only need its main diagonal. So instead of doing `diag(Xp %*% V %*% t(Xp))`, we can do it more efficiently via

```
var.fit <- rowSums((Xp %*% V) * Xp)  ## point-wise variance for predicted mean
#       1        2 
#1.949963 2.598222 

sqrt(var.fit)  ## this agrees with `z$se.fit`
#       1        2 
#1.396411 1.611900
```

The residual degree of freedom is readily available in the fitted model:

```
dof <- df.residual(lmObject)
#[1] 43
```

Finally, to compute residual variance, use Pearson estimator:

```
sig2 <- c(crossprod(lmObject$residuals)) / dof
# [1] 79.45063

sqrt(sig2)  ## this agrees with `z$residual.scale`
#[1] 8.913508
```

**remark**

Note that in case of weighted regression, `sig2` should be computed as

```
sig2 <- c(crossprod(sqrt(lmObject$weights) * lmObject$residuals)) / dof
```

---

### Appendix: a self-written function that mimics `predict.lm`

The code in "Do everything from scratch" has been cleanly organized into a function `lm_predict` in this Q & A: [linear model with `lm`: how to get prediction variance of sum of predicted values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338512/4891738).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there is a quick way to extract the standard error for the prediction interval, but you can always backsolve the intervals for the SE (even though it's not super elegant approach):

```
m <- lm(V1 ~ V2, data = d)                                                                                                                                                                                                                

newdat <- data.frame(V2=6)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
tcrit <- qt(0.95, m$df.residual)                                                                                                                                                                                                          

a <- predict(m, newdat, interval="confidence", level=0.90)                                                                                                                                                                                
cat("CI SE", (a[1, "upr"] - a[1, "fit"]) / tcrit, "\n")                                                                                                                                                                                   

b <- predict(m, newdat, interval="prediction", level=0.90)                                                                                                                                                                                
cat("PI SE", (b[1, "upr"] - b[1, "fit"]) / tcrit, "\n")
```

Notice that the CI SE is the same value from `se.fit`.

Comment: This worked. I backsolved for SE using 89.63 + - t(0.95,43)xSE = Lower Bound where Lower Bound was 87.28 for the CI and 74.46 for the PI. The SE CI was 1.39 and SE PI was 9.02. So the SE for the prediction interval IS greater than the confidence interval. But I still don't understand why the output in R for the prediction interval lists the se.fit = 1.39. Why doesn't it list 9? Thanks!!!

Comment: simple is very elegant ... and also is a good way to practice basic understanding

Comment: In the tcrit <- qt(0.95, m$df.residual), is the 0.95 (instead of 0.90) because it's one-tailed?

In other words, let's say we were looking for an 82% PI, would we use qt(0.91, m$df.residual)?