# Does geom_smooth() of ggplot2 show pointwise confidence bands, or simultaneous confidence bands?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, confidence-interval

I was unsure whether this question would be more appropriate here or on Cross Validated. I hope I made the right choice.

Consider the example:

```
library(dplyr)
setosa <- iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa") %>% select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = setosa, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method ="lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,2))
```

[image]
By default, `ggplot` "displays confidence interval around smooth" (see [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_smooth.html)), given by the gray area around the regression curve. I've always assumed these are [simultaneous confidence bands for the regression curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands), not pointwise confidence bands. `ggplot2` documentation refers to the `predict` function for details on how the standard errors are computed. However, reading the doc for [predict.lm](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/stats/html/predict.lm.html), it doesn't say explicitly that simultaneous confidence bands are computed. So, what is the correct interpretation here?

Comment: I think this is better on the [stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions), as it seems little to do with ggplot, and more to do with asking how the confidence interval is calculated for a linear regression: voted to migrate

Comment: You may find this answer useful: [How does predict.lm() compute confidence interval and prediction interval?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38110406/6455166)

Comment: @WeihuangWong, thanks for the help, but that link you posted discusses the difference between confidence intervals and prediction intervals. I'm not concerned with prediction intervals. I'm only interested in knowing if `predict.lm()`, when used to compute **confidence** bands, computes **simultaneous** confidence bands or **pointwise** confidence bands.

Comment: @user20650, you may be right. I'm specifically asking what type of confidence band `ggplot` is computing (pointwise or simultaneous). That's why in the end I chose to post here. Anyway, it could be that CV is better suited for this question. I'll make a little edit to the title to avoid any confusion, and wait a bit more. If I don't receive any answer, I'll migrate (of course, assuming that moderators haven't already migrated the question by then).

Comment: Hi Delta: as ggplot just uses the code `predict(.., interval = "confidence")` (you can model this by hand and plot to check), so it seems as if the question reduces to what this interval represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to check what `predict.lm()` computes is to inspect the code (`predict` multiplies standard errors by `qt((1 - level)/2, df)`, and so does not appear to make adjustments for simultaneous inference).  Another way is to construct simultaneous confidence intervals and compare them against `predict`'s intervals.

Fit the model and construct simultaneous confidence intervals:

```
setosa <- subset(iris, Species == "setosa")
setosa <- setosa[order(setosa$Sepal.Length), ]
fit <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ poly(Sepal.Length, 2), setosa)

K <- cbind(1, poly(setosa$Sepal.Length, 2))
cht <- multcomp::glht(fit, linfct = K)
cci <- confint(cht)
```

Reshape and plot:

```
cc <- as.data.frame(cci$confint)
cc$Sepal.Length <- setosa$Sepal.Length
cc <- reshape2::melt(cc[, 2:4], id.var = "Sepal.Length")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = setosa, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method ="lm", formula = y ~ poly(x,2)) +
  geom_line(data = cc, 
            aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = value, group = variable),
            colour = "red")
```

It appears that `predict(.., interval = "confidence")` does not produce simultaneous confidence intervals:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you add a little bit of explanation to the code, though? The `ggplot` part is fairly self-explanatory, but some comments about the lines before may make the answer more generally useful. For example, why do you need to reorder `setosa`? What is the function `glht` from package `multcomp` doing?

Comment: Reordering `setosa` is just so that the lines render correctly on the plot (otherwise they would zig-zag back and forth). As for `multcomp::glht`, unfortunately I don't feel confident that I can give you an accurate or useful explanation (beyond that it is a way to get simultaneous confidence bands), so you might be better served posting a follow-up question (either here or on CV).

Comment: Thanks! I was also wondering why you didn't import the package `multcomp`...found out that it masks `dplyr`'s `select`.